# Copying by reference in JS - Why is the output of this code 17?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var obj = { arr: [{ x: 17 }] }; 
var z = obj.arr;
z = [{ x: 25 }]; 
console.log(obj.arr[0].x);
```

Console prints out 17 can someone explain me how?
As per my knowledge z has reference to obj.arr and re-initializing z, console should have print out 25

Comment: That title is just terrible, Create a searchable title and add your example in the body of your post. EDIT: post was edited but OP needs to understand this

Comment: After setting `z` to `obj.arr` you immediately re-set it to a completely new array. That won't affect `obj.arr`.

Comment: I thought z has reference to obj.arr, since its an array. Can you please explain how copying by reference works in JS especially referencing inner object properties.

Comment: @yoyo44 Yes `z` has reference of `obj.arr` but when you do `z = ...`, you are replacing this reference. So it does not affect the original object. But when you do `z.x`, compiler will look for property in object at the specified memory location. Hence, `z.x = ` will update all values.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
z = [{ x: 25 }];
```

will replace the previous value of z. At that point, z has no longer anything to do with "obj".

If you want to change `obj` via `z`, you would need something like

```
z[0].x = 25;
```